# Swift heightForRowAtIndexPath called too many times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

These are my delegate methods for tablerow

```
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }    

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        println(indexPath.row)

        return 300.0;
    }
```

The println in heightForRowAtIndexPath is acting wierd, this is my output:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
```

Why is it called so many times? only 2 cells are being shown in my UI.

Comment: Do you call reloadData() somewhere?

Comment: No, there is no call to deloadData anywhere

Comment: It should not matter how often the data source (or delegate) methods are called. The table view calls them whenever it finds it necessary to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324205/heightforrowatindexpath-being-called-for-all-rows-how-many-rows-in-a-uitablevi